# Estrutura do site com includes

Tags: php, include

Bom dia pessoal. Estou desenvolvendo um novo site mas me surgiu uma duvida aqui referente à estrutura por causa do google. Vou explicar. A estrutura das páginas do site está sendo através de includes, como no arquivo "madeira.php" abaixo. Ou seja, estou montando todo o conteúdo desta página chamando outras páginas inclusive o body através de includes. A minha dúvida é: o google irá indexar todos os arquivos correto? Ou seja, ele poderá mostrar nos resultados tanto a página principal que eu chamei de "madeira.php" quanto o body dela que fiz separado "body-madeira.html"? Isto não irá me prejudicar, uma vez que eu quero que ele mostre somente a página principal que é madeira.php? Se tiver ficado complicado a explicação pergunta aí que esclareço melhor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

  <head>
    
  <?php
   
include "head.html"
?>
    <title>Titulo do site</title>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: comfortaa;">

<!-- puxa o header, ou seja, o menu do seu website -->
<?php
include "header.html"
?>

<!-- puxa o body da pagina teste -->
<?php
include "madeira-body.html"
?>

<!-- puxa a páกgina footer, ou seja, o final do website -->
<?php
include "footer.html"
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ele vai indexar somente uma página, a que faz os includes

Comment: A não ser que as outras estejam disponíveis para listagem, daí ele vai ver a principal e as demais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa,

O google vai indexar somente as páginas que você mandar ele indexar.
Você pode controlar isso com o arquivo ROBOTS.TXT que deve ficar na pasta raíz do projeto, na qual através dele você definirá o que o google está permitido a ler ou não.

Como você está montando uma página toda por include, o google vai interpretar essa página sendo como única, pois no "compilador" do navegador será exibido a página como única, pois cada include contém os elementos do HTML.

Por questões de organização, os arquivos de include eu costumo colocá-las em uma pasta exclusiva (suponhamos que seja nomeada "INCLUDES"). Sendo assim, no seu robots.txt, você informa que a pasta INCLUDES esteja bloqueada (disallow) para que o google não possa ler ou encontrá-la. Desta forma, todos os arquivos dentro desta pasta não serão indexados.

Ao fazer isso, seus includes serão chamados no seu arquivo principal que você exibirá seu site/sistema normalmente, e o google irá indexar como se fosse uma única página.

Espero ter ajudado.

Saiba mais sobre robots.txt: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=pt-BR

Comment: Se a página não estiver no robots.txt e estiver linkada por um `a` em outro local, o google vai ver, ele vai de link em link e indexa, por isso é importante só permitir a listagem de arquivos que precisem ser vistos

Comment: Sim, exatamente Denis, por isso costumo colocar os arquivos de include dentro de uma pasta exclusiva, pois são arquivos "quebrados" que serão juntados para formar um conteúdo.